# Sorting and iterating widget starting from anywhere

Tags: c#

```
List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();
Widget widgetA = new Widget();
Widget widgetB = new Widget();
Widget widgetC = new Widget();
Widget widgetD = new Widget();
Widget widgetE = new Widget();
Widget widgetF = new Widget();
list.AddRange(new[] { widgetA, widgetB, widgetC, widgetD, widgetE, widgetF });
```

What would I need to do to sort starting somewhere in the middle?

for example,

```
list.AddRange(new[] { widgetD, widgetE, widgetF, widgetA, widgetB, widgetC });
```

Or, in other words, start the index somewhere in the middle and then wrap the remaining objects in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Skip`, `Take` and `Union`.

```
List<Widget> widgets = ...

// now to split and wrap
int startIndex = 3;
var newList = widgets.Skip(startIndex)
                     .Union(widgets.Take(startIndex)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort them, then take first few elements and put them at the end.

```
var mid = 2; // starting point
var arr = new[] { widgetA, widgetB, widgetC, widgetD, widgetE, widgetF };
arr.Sort(); //you can use your own comparator for sorting
list.AddRange(arr.Skip(mid).Concat(arr.Take(mid)));
```